# Pushing objects with same keys but different values to array conditionally to avoid typing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, object

I have this array of objects with same keys.

```
 const services = [
  {
    trade: "Electrical",
    expertise: [
      "• Lighting installations",
      "• Facade lighting",
      "• Lighting automation solutions, Low voltage (LV) power distribution",
      "• Emergency lighting",
      "• MV power distribution, Power monitoring systems, Soar power solutions and Vertical Transportation Solar power solutions.",
    ],
    icon: faBolt,
  },
  {
    trade: "Heating, Ventilation & AC (HVAC)",
    expertise: [
      "• Central and distributed chilled water systems, underfloor cooling.",
      "• Microclimate control.",
      "• Variable refrigerant flow (VRF), variable air volume (VAV), split air conditioning and ground source energy systems (geothermal).",
    ],
    icon: faCog,
  },
  {
    trade: "Fire Fighting Systems",
    expertise: [
      "• Sprinkler system, CO2, foam, clean agent suppression systems (NOVAC, FM200 and ENERGIN)",
    ],
    icon: faFireExtinguisher,
  },
  {
    trade: "Plumbing, Drainage & Specialist System",
    expertise: [
      "• Water treatment",
      "• Sewage treatment plants (STP's), solar hot water systems and desalination plant",
    ],
    icon: faWrench,
  },
  {
    trade: "Extra-low voltage (ELV) Systems",
    expertise: [
      " • Building management systems (BMS's)",
      "• Fire alarm system",
      "• Intruder alarms",
      "• Access controls",
      "• Closed circuit television (CCTV)",
      "• Intercoms PA Systems",
      "• PA Systems",
    ],
    icon: faSuperpowers,
  },
];
```

Is there any why to avoid writing these object keys again  and again 9 times and just push these objects to array
. I am thinking conditionally pushing objects based on index using for loop but cannot figure out exact way so that i only write keys once.

i am coding using react. this array is mapped as follow:

```
 {services.map((service, index) => {
            return (
              <Zoom key={index} in={true} timeout={400}>
                <Grid xs={12} md className={classes.gridItemCSServices} item>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={service.icon}
                    spin
                    size="2x"
                    color="#0062ae"
                    fixedWidth
                  ></FontAwesomeIcon>
                  <Typography className={classes.listHeadingCSServices}>
                    {service.trade}
                  </Typography>
                  <ul className={classes.listCSServices}>
                    {service.expertise.map((experty, index) => {
                      return <li key={index}>{experty}</li>;
                    })}
                  </ul>
                </Grid>
              </Zoom>
            );
          })}
```

What would be the best way for such scenarios ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are the values that you assign to the keys?

Comment: First key has string. 2nd key has icon of font awesome.3rd key has array of strings.

Comment: If the values differ, I don't see how/why you'd avoid specifying the keys.

Comment: Do [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65994805/edit) your question to include an actual example of the array in case there is a pattern that could be simplified.

Comment: This code is fine. If you really worry about the duplicated object keys, you could create a function which return a single object and call it for each. `cont serviceFactory = (trade, icon, expertises) => ({ trade, icon, expertises })`